# Disable Debugging Output

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, console

I'd like to sprinkle some print statements in my code to show where I am and print important values to a console window.

How do I do that, but then be able to turn it off for the release version?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All calls to [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.print.aspx) will be removed when you switch to a release version.

Comment: Could also use Trace if you might want the statements in release and debug.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) with logging at debug level in release and warn or error level in production.

Benefit to this is that you can turn logging back on in the release environment if you have problems there that you can't recreate in development.

[EDIT] FWIW, I find that I do a **LOT** less debug logging now that I use Test-Driven Development.  Most of my logging is of the warn/error variety.

Comment: You can do that with using Trace instead of Debug

Comment: I log stuff anyway -- want to know about errors -- so debug logging works better for me.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the System.Diagnostics.Debug and System.Diagnostics.Trace classes.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging and tracing are related but distinct activities.  The `System.Diagnostics` namespace supports them both.

Use `Debug.Write/WriteLine` to write debugging messages to a log file.  (And to the Output window.)  Use `Debug.Assert`, well, pretty much everywhere.  All code that you write using the `Debug` class is removed before complilation if you don't define a DEBUG symbol in your code - this is done by default in the options for Debug and Release configurations.

Use `Trace.Write/WriteLine` to write tracing messages.  These methods are functionally equivalent to the methods of the Debug class; the difference is that they are removed if you don't define a TRACE symbol in your code.

The Debug and Trace classes also have a whole slightly-cumbersome infrastructure of other classes, like `TextWriterTraceListener`, that allow you to do spiffy things like change the output of your trace log from a local file on disk to a web service (or to nothing) just by editing the application configuration file.  My favorite trick is to implement a `TextWriter` that can write text to a `TextBox`, and use that to redirect all the debug and trace output to the UI.

You can also set flags in the app config file that the `WriteIf` and `WriteLineIf` methods respect, but in my experience those get pretty unwieldy.

I find that in general, I'm happier if I build my own static class to wrap the `Trace` methods.  That lets me do things like turn tracing on and off in the UI just by setting a property of my `Trace` class.

Finally:  if you need to instrument your app to do something like trace when every method begins and ends, the tool to use for that is the miraculous PostSharp.

Answer (score 0):

I use: [System.Console.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx)

```
#if DEBUG
  System.Console.WriteLine("Message");
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into Aspect Oriented Programming solutions.  They do this sort of thing really well.  Look at PostSharp as a good implementation.  Their sample code usually contains an example of exactly what you're looking for.